# installing legacy mysql for older version of Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to run an old Rails 4.0 application with mysql and its related data.  Rails gem is `mysql2 (0.4.2)` Database data is coming from a server versions `5.6.44`

bash_profile has

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin:$PATH"
```

bundle install process completes as expected, but when launching the server, the connection to the database is failing

```
rbenv/versions/2.2.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in `connect': Access denied for user
```

I attempt to adjust my connection mechanism by the sql command:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
```

however, upon:

```
sudo mysql
Password:
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.47/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found
```

So it appears I am in a sort of logical loop as there is no plugin download for the `caching_sha2_password`

What is the way out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line: In this context, the following cannot be executed

```
create user 'USER_NAME'@'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD';
```

as Homebrew has versions 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0  but ones where the set-up requires the `caching_sha2_password` plugin (introduced sometime during the 5.6 cycle apparently).  Although root has no password, one cannot login as root `mysql  -uroot` for this very reason.

Once it is accepted that this is a damned-if-you-do, damned-if-you-don't situation, time to move unconventionally...

I attempted to install both 5.6 and 8.0 via homebrew to import the mysql database under 8, but access it as 5.6. Whale fail.  Exact same behaviour: root invariably needs access via sha2_password.

**Solution**

1. the mysql2 gem requires a version to hook up to. Given the version on the application `0.4.2`, this meant

   brew install mysql@5.6
2. go to https://downloads.mysql.com  and find the appropriate community server installer for the OS to run on. Install.  This application will allow root to login.

But now the connection to the database has to be the one to the downloaded application, not the homebrew keg (that's there to allow the application's gem to run).  So the `.bash_profile` needs to have

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

which points to the installed version rather than the homebrew one.

Now:

```
create user 'deploy'@'localhost' identified by 'some_nasty_string';
bundle exec rails db < my_db.sql
rails s
```

Get on with working.

One could also ponder about the interestingly seamless consequence of importing a mysql 5.6 database into 8.0

*[Posted for anyone who has to dig up old material and make it evolve & to remember these hoops.]*